# CMake: custom_target argument forwarding to specific command

Tags: python, cmake

I would like to execute a python script while having a python virtual environment activated.
This script (`run_smth.py`) has input parameters.

Is there a possibility to create custom target `run_my_script` in such a way that after configuration it is possible to just type `make run_my_script arg1 arg2` and this would be equal to `. /path_to_venv/bin/activate && python3 run_smth.py arg1 arg2`?

The thing is that I want to be able to execute this script in a convenient way when CMake configuration is done.

Comment: Yes, you can do this, but getting the arguments passed through `make` to the custom target is difficult, if not impossible. How static are these arguments `arg1 arg2`? This would be achievable if you set them at CMake configure time (i.e. `cmake -DARG1=arg1 -DARG2=arg2`).

Comment: @squareskittles To be more specific, it's all about running some automated testing manually. In order to do it someone need to a) activate python virtual environment (created via special target inside build folder); b) call python script which is placed somewhere in src directory.  This script has some flags (like path to config/test pattern, etc). I want to avoid step 'a' and messing with relative paths, just call e.g. 'make run_tests -sanity'

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any support for passing arguments to a CMake custom target as you've described. The arguments would need to be passed through `make` in your case, but CMake would also need to support passing them through Visual Studio, Ninja, and the other generators.

Therefore, one way I could see this working would be to hard-code the arguments during the CMake configuration stage. You could configure CMake, and pass the arguments you intend to run the custom target with:

```
cmake -DARG1=arg1 -DARG2=arg2 ..
```

This would encapsulate the arguments in `ARG1` and `ARG2` CMake variables, so your [custom target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html) could look something like this:

```
add_custom_target(run_my_script
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/path_to_venv/bin/activate 
        && python3 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/run_smth.py ${ARG1} ${ARG2}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
)
```

This assumes your `run_smth.py` script is in the same directory as the CMake file containing this command, through use of [`CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR.html). Similarly, that directory is used as the working directory for running the python script.

If setting the script arguments at the CMake configuration stage is too restrictive, you could also create multiple CMake custom targets (e.g. some for different test patterns, like `run_my_script_sanity` and `run_my_script_regression`):

```
# Create a custom target for the sanity tests.
add_custom_target(run_my_script_sanity
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/path_to_venv/bin/activate 
        && python3 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/run_smth.py -sanity ${ARG2}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
)
# Create a custom target for the regression tests.
add_custom_target(run_my_script_regression
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/path_to_venv/bin/activate 
        && python3 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/run_smth.py -regression ${ARG2}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. Probably there is something in predefining custom targets for specific configurations, but anyway if I don't find a way to forward arguments as I see it I will have to write one more script to do what I want. Yes, I know about CMake arguments, but I don't want to force other developers to reconfigure project if they need to run tests with different options.